# (JavaScript) Can't it be declared other than declaring a variable as a constructor in a class?

Tags: javascript

(I am using google translator)

```
class User{
    name="tom"
    showName(){
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
const tom = new User()
console.log(tom.name)
```

The code above prints Tom .
But if I change the second line like this, I get an error.

```
var name="Tom"
let name="Tom"
const name="Tom"
this.name="Tom"
```

Comment: It is not a variable, it is a [field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations). You cannot declare a variable there.

Comment: It isn't a variable.

Comment: Why would you change the lines to become invalid syntax? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The way class field syntax was designed, such a line can do *one* thing: it assigns to a property of the instance.

`this.name = "tom"` isn't syntactically permitted because it would have been redundant.

`var name =` and other variants aren't permitted in that position because those are variable declaration keywords (`var`, `let`, `const`) - which keyword you use has various implications on the scope of the newly created variable, and whether it can be reassigned. But this makes no sense in the context of a class field, because you aren't creating a new identifier, you're assigning to a property of an object.

This

```
class User{
    name="tom"
```

is the same as doing

```
class User{
    constructor() {
        this.name = "tom";
    }
```

`name` is not a new variable created in a particular scope - it's only a property, so using `var`, `let`, or `const` when declaring it would mix two entirely separate concepts, and so is forbidden.

So, you can only do

```
class User{
    name="tom"
```

(Unless you want the property to be private (only useable from the inside of the class), in which case prefix the property name with a `#`.)

```
class User{
    #name="tom"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted in your question is to know another way to declare variables in a js class. So, you can use a constructor to achieve that, something like that:

```
class User{
    constructor() {
        this.name = "tom"
    }
 
    showName(){
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
const tom = new User()
console.log(tom.name)
```

That’ll print "tom" as well.